# Login to computer with Android phone

Tags: login, android, unlock

Is it possible to login or unlock my Ubuntu computer with my android phone over WiFi? I am looking for some functionality like that offered by rohos logon key for windows and osx which unlocks the computer by tapping on the phone when the phone and computer are on the same WiFi network.

I am aware that this is possible with Bluetooth, but my computer does not have built in Bluetooth and i am not willing to get a USB Bluetooth dongle.

Basically I want my android phone and Ubuntu computer on the same wifi network, and want to unlock my computer by tapping on my phones screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install a ssh server on your computer. and login though ssh using your phone. You need to be on genome for it to work.

Install ssh server on your Computer

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

If you are on gnome you can unlock your screen with this command.

```
ssh -X user@server "export DISPLAY=:0; gnome-screensaver; gnome-screensaver-command -d;"
```

i am not a phone person but if you are able to run that command as a short cut using [Rom Tool Box](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.liberty.toolbox&hl=en) it might work. you might want to ask [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) about that.

[Remote Lock Screen and Remote Unlock Screen on Linux (Ubuntu)](http://z-computer-z.blogspot.co.nz/2010/01/remote-lock-screen-and-remote-unlock.html)

Unsure if it is what you are looking for but keep in mind Windows, XOS and Linux are completely different operating systems.

Comment: I understand that they are different OSes, but I want that functionality. I will try it with ssh tomorrow